# Problem with Symfony - My console turns indefinitely

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

First of all, sry for my english.

I have a problem with symfony/console i guess.

I install a project  of my
company, the setup is really a mess and i'm here to migrate symfony and clean everything !

First the version of importants things :

- PHP 7.4.9
- Symfony 4.4.22 (obv same for the symfony/console)
- jms/job-queue-bundle dev-master (was my problem for sure)

My problem is simple I can't use my console, and i don't have error !
Nothing is touched at the bin/console level AT LEAST the import of Application, they use that `use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application;`. But `php bin/console` or `symfony console`
turns indefinitely (or a LOOOOOONG time) !

Through the vendor I see the pathing of my code

```
//bin/console
-----
$application->run($input);  
-----

//jms/job-queue-bundle/JMS/JobQueueBundle/Console/Application.php
public function doRun(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
.
.
    try {
        $rs = parent::doRun($input, $output);
        .
        .
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
.
.
-----

/!\ AT THIS POINT the bundle go on this class when the official Application go to symfony/console/application
//vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php
public function doRun(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->registerCommands();
.
.
protected function registerCommands() {
if ($container->hasParameter('console.command.ids')) {
    $lazyCommandIds = $container->hasParameter('console.lazy_command.ids') ? $container->getParameter('console.lazy_command.ids') : [];
        foreach ($container->getParameter('console.command.ids') as $id) {
            if (!isset($lazyCommandIds[$id])) {
                try {
                    print_r($id);
                    $this->add($container->get($id));
                } catch (\Throwable $e) {
```

On this loop, i find that every add take at least 5-10 sec, but the add() of JMS just do an parent::add from the official symfony/console.

So i'm really blocked and think about to delete all of this mess and just try to run everythink with the official console but i want to understand.

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you using dotenv ? do specific bin/console commands work? Is the `jms/job-queue-bundle` up to date? Maybe you should try a tagged version

Comment: Yes we have dotend. all of the other bon/console doesn't work, turn infinitly and don't catch any error. Absolutly not it's an old bundle i want to totally remove it but if I can't launch the project, that could be a mess to migrate this project :/

Comment: If there is no output, maybe the file bin/console is not executable? `chmod u+x bin/console`.

Comment: Nope, bin/console turn, `print_r($id);` work but take 100000hours to loop all this command, maybe a parameter php ?

Comment: Sounds like the original environment does not match with your current. Maybe It´s worth a shot try to update `composer update -W --dry-run`  (-W = with all dependencies)

Comment: did you install vendor with composer?`